# How do I get a d3 graph to update in a loop?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to have this bar chart dynamically update while looping through date values:

```
var currDate = 20140101;
var dat = null;
d3.csv("TrafficOverTime.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  function next(){
      dat = data.filter(function(d){
        if (d.date === currDate){
            return d;
        }
          });
      currDate++;
  };
  function redraw(dat){
      y.domain([0, d3.max(dat, function(d) {
        return d.visitors; 
      })]);
      var barWidth = width / dat.length;
      var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
          .data(dat)
          .enter()
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) { 
              return "translate(" + i * barWidth + ",0)"; 
          });

      bar.append("rect")
          .transition()
          .delay(100)   
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.visitors); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.visitors); })
          .attr("width", barWidth - 1);

      bar.append("text")
          .attr("x", barWidth / 2)
          .attr("y", function(d) { 
            return y(d.visitors) + 3; 
        })
          .attr("dy", ".75em")
          .text(function(d) { return d.visitors; });
    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range([height, 0]);
  };

  setInterval(function(){
      next();
      redraw(dat);
      }, 1000
  );

});
```

A `console.log` statement reveals that the data is within scope of those functions and properly updating based on the filter, but the graph is not redrawing. Any thoughts on why this might be?

Example data:

```
page,date,visitors
home,20140101,60000
signup,20140101,40000
login,20140101,10000
home,20140102,70000
signup,20140102,50000
login,20140101,12000
home,20140103,65000
signup,20140103,45000
login,20140103,15000
...
```

Comment: The data is matched to existing elements and so the enter selection is empty and nothing happens. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I want a bar chart that updates for each day in my data.

Comment: Do you mean that the bars should appear one by one as for example [here](http://nvd3.org/examples/multiBar.html)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff More like this [here](http://nvd3.org/examples/discreteBar.html), except that for each subsequent day, the bars transitions from the old day's values to that new day's values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing a change is that you have the same number of data elements and later data is matched to the existing DOM elements. Therefore, the enter selection is empty and nothing happens.

Based on your comments, code to redraw should look something like this, binding the new data and then updating the existing elements based on it instead of appending new elements.

```
var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
      .data(dat);

bar.select("rect")
   .transition()
   .delay(100)   
   .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.visitors); })
   .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.visitors); });

bar.select("text")
   .attr("y", function(d) { 
        return y(d.visitors) + 3; 
    })
   .text(function(d) { return d.visitors; });
```